# NUnit has stopped working in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit

I am running NUnit 2.6.3 in VS2012 with NUnit Test Adapater 1.1.0.0, on 64 bit Windows 7. The project is C# winforms.

My project's unit tests have stopped running from within VS. I can launch NUnit directly and run the project OK, but running or debugging tests from within VS just greys them out with this message in the output window:

> No test is available in
>   [Your Output Path].
>   Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform &
>   framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Any pointers of what that means? Where can I find the "platform and framework version settings" - does it refer to NUnit settings, project settings, VS settings, or one of the NUnit plugin settings?
I *think* that it's related to me updating to the latest version of the Test Adapter, but unfortunately I'm not sure :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have fixed it by:
 - Updating my project target to .NET framework 4.5 from 3.5 (which my project was in - not my choice!). I cannot find any documentation stating this as a limitation, so perhaps it's a bug.

(I have also changed to using NuGet to install NUnit to the project instead of the VS plugin, but I'm not sure that had an effect).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but when I tried to run my tests just showed that yellow inconclusive circle.

I ended up solving my problem by going into the bin folder for my project, deleting the NUnit framework dll files and then re-running the tests. Worked like a charm.